# Is it OK for a user to ask other users to vote for him as a quid pro quo for voting their questions?

Tags: discussion, policy, serial-voting

Perhaps it is not an issue in sites like MathOverflow because it is really shameful for a prestigious professor to get involve in such childish games but in Math.Stackexchange it could happen.

Here there are many users who greedily seek for higher reputation thresholds. According to the site policies establishing satellite accounts and voting between them is not allowed and the user will be punished if this behavior is spotted.

But what if this voting irregularities happen between different users as a kind of agreement? A user A upvotes almost every post of another user B. In response the user B votes for almost every post of the user A. Both will get higher reputations and this is not "illegal" because they are different users.

What is the site's policy in such cases?

Comment: Nothing was ever officially confirmed, but there was a series of suspensions recently (involving a lot of high-profile users) along with a lot of votes reversals, and it was suspected that the users in question did engage in what you describe here: a "voting ring" of sorts. (The users in question were pretty much gloating in the public chat about their "system", to be fair...)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Is this a voting ring or a voting group? Are voters associative?

Comment: Personally I don't see the hype...it's pretty sad if you think you "need" stack exchange votes that much to get on in life. They don't equate to money or anything else that is valuable...

Comment: @fretty higher self confidence, power, influence on the site

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is not allowed to make deals about mutual voting, definitely not explicitly and  not even implicitly. This would be considered as a voting-ring. Even to just vote on many of a user's post because  you might find the user is a friendly person brings you quickly on very thin ice.

Such behavior can lead quickly to reversal of votes and even to suspensions.

Comment: To be sure, it is fine if you have a friend whose posts you like to read and upvote; just make sure you are actually reading their posts carefully and upvoting them based on their merits, not just because your friend wrote them!

Comment: Actually, I would even recommend some caution in this situation. It is better to vote on posts as one finds them on the site, rather than to go through some friend's recent activity.  In that case I think how this is seen will depend mainly on how much of one's relative activity this voting for a friend is.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the answer. It is really nice that I can't find any *critical typo* in this answer of yours! Maybe because my question is very simple and clear and you didn't have that much trouble to get its point!

Comment: @A.M. While I am glad you are satisfied,  you cannot have read my post carefully enough when you did not find a typo there.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to an official statement by moderators somewhere that they clarified the policy in this situation?

Comment: @A.M. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138517/how-to-vote-on-friends-colleagues-questions-or-answers As you can see it is quite strict; see my reply to Eric that I feel is in line with what is said there. Note that Bill the Lizard while not a moderator at the moment was a highly active and influential SO mod for many years.

Comment: @quid Is this the first post that you've answered with your [user]name in the title?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman   At some point somebody complained about me on MO, and I commented. I think they had my name in the title. For more coincidental appearance, I might have forgotten or not noticed.  But regarding this title perhaps also ask http://math.stackexchange.com/users/212220/quidproquo :-)

Comment: Something that sometimes happens to me is: I find an answer I like, I go and read other answers by the same user. To me, that's a perfectly honest way of learning interesting new things, and it is bound to make me upvote this person's answers a lot. Should I be worried?

Comment: @PseudoNeo I suppose it depends on volume. If you stumble across some answers you like and cast a handful of upvotes, it will not cause any issue. (Also note that even an occasional auto-reversal of serial voting is I think inconsequential.) If you read through a list of 2000 answers at a rate of 20 per day and vote on 10 of them each day not doing much else on the site it likely will result in some questions. Anyway, I do not want to create any paranoia here. Just do not go overboard with concentration of votes even if they seem deserved, and things should be fine.

Comment: This comment makes so much sense I'm going to create a gazillion of accounts to upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I would say certainly not.

However,
I have adopted a few practices:

First,
whenever someone finds an error
in one of my answers,
I *always* upvote their correction.
My hope is that
this will encourage others
to read my answers,
since my probability
of making an error
is definitely non-zero.

Second,
if someone posts the
only correct answer
to a question,
I post a comment
(to the original question)
encouraging the OP
to accept it, if they have
not done so.

Third,
and less relevantly,
I enjoy a conversation
consisting of a
series of comments
about answers,
despite MSE's
occasional suggestions of
"why don't you two find a room!"